# How to remove new line character at end of line ending with a number?

Tags: shell-script

i have a file like that shown below. I want to remove newline character if the line ends with a number (preferably `sed` or `awk`).

file.txt:

```
some question:       1404241

what's your name?

1498646

my name is Bond.
```

So I want the output like below:

```
some question:       1404241 what's your name? 

1498646 my name is Bond.
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually given your input/output - you're removing multiple new lines. That makes the problem slightly harder, because things like `sed` - *as standard* iterate one line at a time.

I'll suggest using something like perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#read everything
local $/;
#do replacement of a digit, following by one - or more - linefeeds. 
#m is multi-line, r is 'return the result' (to print)
#g is do it repeatedly. 
print <DATA> =~ s/(\d)\n+/$1 /mrg;

__DATA__
some question:       1404241

what's your name?

1498646

my name is Bond.
```

This prints:

```
some question:       1404241 what's your name?

1498646 my name is Bond.
```

This can be turned into a one liner:

```
perl -0777 -e 'print <> =~ s/(\d)\n+/$1 /mgr'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e:n -e'$!N;s/\([0-9]\)\n/\1/;tn' -eP\;D <infile >outfile
```

...so that does the removal as you request, but it doesn't get the result you request. Probably what you want is to replace a newline following a number with a space, right?

```
sed -e:n -e'/[0-9]$/{$!N;s/\n$//;}' -etn -e's/\n/ /' <infile >outfile
```

...that should be more efficient, anyway.